# How can I convert this Python code into a SQLAlchemy query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, subquery, querying

I'm building a data dashboard for a project where players field a certain position within a game. Players can also field multiple positions in a single game. The dashboard needs the following data:

- Each player in the Player table
- The number of games that player has appeared in, regardless of whether they appeared in multiple positions in that game. (i.e. if Fred appears at 3 positions each in 2 games, the query should return 2 not 6)
- The winning percentage of games in which that player appeared. (i.e. if John appears in 20 games and 11 of them have `outcome="Win", the query should return 0.55)

I wrote some Python code that accomplishes this. It's very slow and requires a number of database queries in a loop. Is it possible to achieve the same output from a single query?

```py
from sqlalchemy import func, select

def get_player_winning_percentages():
    """
    Returns a list of all players who have appeared in a game, along with the
    number of games they've appeared in (regardless of how many times they
    appeared in each game) and the winning percentage of games they've appeared in.
    Output looks like:
    [("John", 20, 0.55), ("Alejandro", 15, 0.75), ("Fred", 13, 0.5), ...]
    """
    # Get all players who have appeared in a game
    players_query = (
        Player.query.join(GameToPlayerPosition)
        .group_by(Player.id)
        .order_by(func.count(Player.id).desc())
    )
    # For each player with an appearance, find the number of games they've appeared in,
    # and the number of winning games they've appeared in.
    data = []
    for player in players_query.all():
        games = Game.query.filter(
            Game.players.any(Player.name == player.name)
        ).count()
        wins = Game.query.filter(
            Game._outcome == "Win",
            Game.players.any(Player.name == player.name)
        ).count()
        data.append({
            "name": player.name, "count": games, "wins": wins
        })
    
    # Find players who haven't appeared in a game and add them to the data
    no_appearances = Player.query.filter(
        ~Player.id.in_(select(players_query.subquery().c.id))
    ).all()
    data += [{"name": player.name, "count": 0, "wins": 0} for player in no_appearances]
    return data
```

My database tables look like this:

```py
# I'm using sqlalchemy and Flask_SQLAlchemy
from my_flask_app import db
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

class Game(db.Model):
    """
    Represents a game. Each game can have several players at different positions.
    A single player can appear in a game multiple times at different positions
    (i.e. have multiple GameToPlayerPosition associations).
    """
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # "Win" or "Loss"
    outcome = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    ... # Other fields
    positions = db.relationship(
        "GameToPlayerPosition", back_populates="game", cascade="all, delete"
    )
    players = association_proxy(
        "positions",
        "player",
        creator=lambda player, position: GameToPlayerPosition(player=player, position=position),
    )

class GameToPlayerPosition(db.Model):
    """
    Association table connecting Game to Player. Adds some additional information,
    namely the `position` column shown here.
    """
    game_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey("game.id"), primary_key=True)
    player_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(f"player.id"), primary_key=True)
    position = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    ... # Other fields
    game = db.relationship("Game", back_populates="positions")
    player = db.relationship("Player", back_populates="game_positions")

class Player(db.Model):
    """Players in a game."""
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False, unique=True)
    ... # Other fields
    game_positions = db.relationship(
        "GameToPlayerPosition", back_populates="player", cascade="all, delete"
    )
    games = association_proxy("game_positions", "game")
```

Comment: [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)

Comment: @philipxy I appreciate the feedback. I took one more stab at a revision. I added a specific question request and included some code I wrote that accomplishes what I want, but in an inefficient way. If you still think this post is ill-formed, I'm happy to delete it or have it closed. I could also see the post as-written-now being maybe better suited for the code-review community, but since I'm unsure (and clearly not doing a great job with this question), I figured I'd start with this edit. Thanks again.

Comment: ... Per the link in my 1st comment, query code parallels a predicate for desired rows. What are the predicates for your goal & the parts you can & can't do? Clearly you could try to give code for the first bullet, then for bullet 2, then 1 & 2, then 3, then 1&3, then 1&2&3. what is stopping you from asking about obvious subgoals/parts you are stuck at? (Rhetorical.) PS Again, PLEASE "try to code per my 1st link"--What is the PREDICATE for your goal & any part you can do or can't do?--Using columns as placeholders in a parameterized statement that a row makes.

Comment: You could probably reasonably ask how to convert a loop over rows into a non-looping query that asks for the same result. Despite 15+ years of SO I wouldn't be surprised if that were a non-duplicate question. But the problem is, to CLEARLY ask what you want is almost certainly most simply expressible--& perhaps only clearly expressible--in terms of getting a certain set of rows--the set of rows that make certain predicate true. At which point you just need to convert the predicate into the corresponding nested algebraish SQL expression that calculates it per the Q&A answer in my 1st comment.